# Is every planar graph a possible dual graph of a voronoi diagram?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, voronoi-diagram

My question is: Given a planar graph defined by its adjacency matrix. Can I always find a set of points, so that the dual graph of the voronoi diagram of that set of points is the same as the planar graph?

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** given a Voronoi diagram $\mathcal{D}$ and its dual graph $(\mathcal{V}, \mathcal{E})$ consider a "face" of the graph (a bounded connected component of its complement), and the set of all vertices at the boundary of that face. Then  all sites of $\mathcal{D}$ corresponding to these vertices lie on the same circle.

**Corollary:**
If the graph below was the dual to a Voronoi diagram, then the three sites corresponding to the vertices in the middle would have to all lie on *two different circles*, which is impossible. Note that there is not only one way to embed this graph in the plane, but the other ways fail to the same argument.

[image]